# GIT: Update Repository in GIT Bash, GIT GUI still shows old repository

Tags: git, repository

I'm very new to GIT, and am getting use to the command line interface and how everything fits together. So, please excuse any inaccuracies or wrong verbiage. Corrections and constructive criticism happily accepted. Now onto my problem.

I initially created a git repository through GIT GUI. It was in the correct folder, but then I started playing around with GIT Bash. There I used the command line:

```
$ git init
```

There, it moved the .git folder to another directory showing the source files for datagrip, atom and some other programs. I then did the following to initialize .git in the correct folder.

```
$ cd "Path"   'Moved to the correct path
$ git init    'Reinitialized existing Git repository
$ git ls -la  'Verified the .git folder
$ git .add    'Just to get a snapshot of everything there, not sure if it was needed
$ git .commit 'Commit all of the files in the repository
$ git .log    'Verify my commit
$ git status  'Verify that there is nothing to commit
```

Everything went well, but when I opened GIT GUI after making these changes, the GIT GUI window showing all of the files, was still in the original folder. I'm not sure what went wrong, if anything did. Do I have to take another action to sync GIT GUI and the changes made in GIT Bash? Did I create a new repository?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
SpicyKoalaBear

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to move the .git directory. Just run "git init" in the root directory of your project. Also, what are you referring to as the "git UI"?

Comment: GIT UI is GIT GUI, it was installed when I installed GIT. I ran "git init" in the root directory of my project. But, GIT GUI is still mapping to the old folder.

Comment: I just set the Home location of git to a root folder that I want. But, GIT GUI is still mapping to the original path. Not sure where to go from here, but I'll keep on looking.